# The Speed of different combining arrays method with Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift, it seems to be having a problem with the speed of combining arrays. I had tried out different method to optimize the time of data copying.

Here is the sample:

```
var sample = [Double](count: 65536, repeatedValue: 0)
```

And four different tests:

```
var test1 = sample + sample
var test2 = sample[0..<sample.count] + sample
var test3 = sample + sample[0..<sample.count]
var test4 = sample[0..<sample.count] + sample[0..<sample.count]
```

the results with above tests(Xcode 6.1):

```
test1: 0.430536985397339
test2: 0.430070996284485
test3: 0.0863670110702515
test4: 0.0846830010414124
```

I think this should be a bug because it can optimize the code simply by adding the square brackets at the end!

Isn't it?

Comment: Problem is you don't have four arrays, you have two arrays and two slices.  It's like comparing apples and contiguously-stored views of apples.

Comment: As a side note, please don't forget that Swift is still very early in its life and very often doesn't live up to its performance promise simply because the optimizer doesn't handle all cases very well. So it's probably not worth it to try to heavily optimize code unless you REALLY have to (and when you do, don't be surprised if perf. characteristics change over time).

Comment: @CodaFi test1&3 should be array and test2&4 should be slice.